# How do I make a button that will print out more text every click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm rather new to programming, but let's keep going. My goal is to create a button that when pressed it will print out text. If you press a second time, it will print out text below the original snippet and so on. Basically, if you keep clicking the button you'll get text repeated a number of times below each other. Currently I've achieved a button that when pressed it prints out text. Press it again and it does nothing. Here's the code I used:

```
<input type="button" value="Duplicate Text" onclick="dup()"/>
<p id="clone"></p>
<script>
function dup() {document.getElementById("clone").innerHTML="Text";}
</script>
```

I'm sure I've done something wrong. Thanks a million.
If you're convinced that it should work, try it. It WILL print out text, but then when you do it a second time, it does nothing.

Comment: instead of using "=" you can use "+=" in this way the string gets extended every time with "Text". This is not a very good solution. It is better to create a new element and append it to your body or div. Like in the answers below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below example is self explanatory

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/YzqML/

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var h = document.createElement("p");
        var t = document.createTextNode("Hello World");
        h.appendChild(t);
        document.body.appendChild(h);
    }
</script>

<p id="demo">Click the button to make more text within a "p" tag.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Another example with `checkbox` and `label`

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/YzqML/1/

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var div = document.getElementById('myItems'),
            clone = div.cloneNode(true);
        document.body.appendChild(clone);
    }
</script>
<div id="myItems">
    <label>My Label</label>
    <input type="checkbox" />
</div>
<p id="demo">Click the button to clone the above items</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Comment: That works, thanks, but can it be used for things other than text? Let's say I wanted to "clone" checkboxes and a drop down list. Would the code just become slightly longer? Or do you need to take other things into account?

Comment: This can be applied to any element. I could provide an example if you wish.

Comment: I think I get it now, but an example might be useful just to be sure. Thank you.

Comment: I've added another example.

Answer (score 0):

You can create new elements and append them to the DOM, like this:

```
function display(msg) {
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  p.innerHTML = String(msg);
  document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

Each time you call the `display` function, the string you give it is added to a new paragraph (`p` element) on the page, which is added to the bottom of the `body`.

Answer (score 0):

I note a jquery tag in your question , so you can do this :

```
   <input type="button" value="Duplicate Text" onclick="$('<p />').appendTo('body')"/>
```

**DEMO :** 
http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/GZu38/1/

Answer (score 0):

Copy paste this code in an html file and run in a browser. If you could include Jquery, then more simpler the code would be.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var h = document.createElement("p");
        var t = document.createTextNode("Hello World");
        h.appendChild(t);
        document.body.appendChild(h);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="demo">Click the button to make more text within a "p" tag.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
</body>
</html>
```